# socket.io client namespace authorization

Tags: authentication, node.js, authorization, real-time, socket.io

Node.js seems to have a knack for acquiring useful modules with insufficient or no documentation.  socket.io is one such module.  I would like to use the built-in authorization feature, for namespaces, but I don't know how that would work, on the client-side.  Server side, they provide sufficient documentation, but beyond that I'm not sure.

**EDIT**: I don't want to know how to get cookie data from the client--I know how to do that, but rather how to directly pass data (e.g. username & password) from the client, via javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's plenty of decent documentation regarding Authorization with Socket.IO: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing (scroll down to "Namespace authorization" and "How does the client handle the global authorization")

What specifically are you trying to achieve?  It sounds a little like you're trying to "POST" a username/password via Socket.IO.  Socket.IO auth happens during the handshake phase, so you could feasibly do the following:

- "Emit" a username/password combination (hope you're using TLS) after a generic authorization and disconnect the user after a bad auth (Pretty mediocre approach IMO)
- Rely on server-side session information for auth instead.  This is probably the desired approach as your server-side handshakeData should contain everything you need to figure out if a user is auth-ed or not.  It'd behoove you to rely on authenticating an HTTP session prior to connecting to socket so that you're not transmitting a username/password combination every time you try to connect to socket.io (which could feasibly be a lot if you fall back on XHR).  There are quite a few articles about this but here's a good start: http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/

Comment: For this particular project I'm guarenteed Websockets, and they're TLS.  Most of my codebase is in PHP, and I'm just using Node.js for realtime synchronization--I'd rather not have to change my session cookies to be accessible for both PHP and Node.js.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to change your session cookies.  If you're using a decentralized session store (like Redis for example) you could query against the store directly.  For example:

`io.of('/private').authorization(function (handshakeData, callback) {
    sessionStore.get(cookie['sid'], function(err, session) {
        if (err || !session) {
            callback('Error', false);
        } else {
            data.session = session;
            callback(null, true);
        }
    });
});`

Comment: You don't seem to understand: there are two problems with this.  First, I'm not using session cookies, and second, I have a framework for a separate part of this project for session cookies that's written in PHP.

Comment: If you have no access to sessions whatsoever, you could ignore handshakeData entirely and make a callout to your PHP auth API after a handshake is complete.  So basically the first bullet I mentioned.  Allow a complete handshake and take care of your own auth.  You could also use a query parameter in your handshake to handle the auth but then you'd have to deal with that being sent on every handshake.  Again, it's hard to figure out exactly what you're trying to do based on your post, but your architecture seems limiting from the get-go.

Comment: It is indeed highly limiting, but I hardly have a choice.  I was reassigned to this project very close to the deadline, and am now the only one working on it.  With no time to restructure it, I'm forced to work around the architecture.  Were I to have more time I'd likely rewrite it.  Thanks for you help, though!

Comment: The documentation is crap, and describes nothing about how to pass data from the client side.  Not everyone is using Socket.IO in a typical web application.  This answer isn't much help either.

Comment: +1 for the Daniel Baulig link. That did a much better job explaining the integration of the "handshake" object.